# SignalR and ASP.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr

What is Signalr built in top of?What are the technologies used to develop Signalr?Is it a combination of JavaScript Libraries and C Sharp files?While developing web apps with Signalr is it  mandatory to update the JQuery libraries.Does new version of JQuery and Signalr lib causes stable application?Can we build Signalr applications using older versions of Asp.net?

Comment: Is this topics available in docs? If not, then this should be included, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SignalR is built both with .NET libraries and with JavaScript libraries.  SignalR is presently dependent on jQuery, but it can be decoupled from jQuery with a bit of work ([implement signalR without jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812849/implement-signalr-without-jquery)).  I believe that it was originally targeted to support .NET 4 or better, but there is a version available for .NET 3.5

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: And if you want to see first hand how it's put together, why not look at the source code? - https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Answer (score 3):

The need for SignalR comes when you need to build a web application (server) that calls a method on the client (browser/mobile apps etc).

Thus, there are two parts to SignalR -- the web server, and the client.

The server part is built on top of .NET Framework. .NET 4.5 is required for the support of Web Sockets. You can look up how to program the server part at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs

The client part can be JavaScript, C# or any other implementations (there is an ObjectiveC implementation). If you are using JavaScript, then it would be best to update your jQuery to the latest version. The JavaScript client tutorial is at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs and C# client tutorial is at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-Client-Hubs

I've been using the RTM version of SignalR (release a few days ago) and latest version of jQuery and they are stable.

You can add SignalR to your existing projects, as long as you upgrade your existing projects to .NET 4.5. SignalR itself has no dependency on WebForms or MVC or WebPages. You will be creating SignalR server code by inheriting from the Hub class, and then wire up your clients (be it in aspx or cshtml) to your server by including the SignalR JavaScript libraries.

Comment: I understand the server will make a rpc to javascript, even objective-c, but how does it work with C# as client code?

Comment: You can use C# to write desktop, Windows Store, Windows Phone, iOS and Android apps